# Инициализация полей для подключения к БД через args[]

Tags: java, инициализация

Добрый день. Сейчас разбираюсь в чужом проекте, который идеально работает и очень мне нужен. Мне не понятно как программа инициализирует поля для дальнейшего подключения к БД. Там везде задействованы `args[]`. Откуда в них берутся значения?

Есть такие классы

```
public class ApplicationProperties {

    public static final ApplicationProperties PROPS = new ApplicationProperties();

    private String dataBase;
    private String dataBaseUrl;
    private String userName;
    private String userPassword;
    private Integer fieldsCount;

    public String getDataBase() {
        return dataBase;
    }

    public void setDataBase(String dataBase) {
        this.dataBase = dataBase;
    }

    public String getDataBaseUrl() {
        return dataBaseUrl;
    }

    public void setDataBaseUrl(String dataBaseUrl) {
        this.dataBaseUrl = dataBaseUrl;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserPassword() {
        return userPassword;
    }

    public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
    }

    public Integer getFieldsCount() {
        return fieldsCount;
    }

    public void setFieldsCount(Integer fieldsCount) {
        this.fieldsCount = fieldsCount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ApplicationProperties{" +
                "dataBase='" + dataBase + '\'' +
                ", dataBaseUrl='" + dataBaseUrl + '\'' +
                ", userName='" + userName + '\'' +
                ", userPassword='" + userPassword + '\'' +
                ", fieldsCount=" + fieldsCount +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Потом есть класс, где поля инициализируются

```
ApplicationProperties.PROPS.setDataBase(args[0].toUpperCase());
ApplicationProperties.PROPS.setDataBaseUrl(args[1]);
ApplicationProperties.PROPS.setUserName(args[2]);
ApplicationProperties.PROPS.setUserPassword(args[3]);
```

И класс где идет подключение

```
public class DataSourceFactory {
    public static DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

        String driverClassName = AppConstants.JDBC_DRIVERS.get(ApplicationProperties.PROPS.getDataBase());
        if (driverClassName == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String databaseUrl = AppConstants.JDBC_URLS_PREFIX.get(ApplicationProperties.PROPS.getDataBase()) +
                ApplicationProperties.PROPS.getDataBaseUrl();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(databaseUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(ApplicationProperties.PROPS.getUserName());
        dataSource.setPassword(ApplicationProperties.PROPS.getUserPassword());
        dataSource.setPoolPreparedStatements(true);
        dataSource.setMaxOpenPreparedStatements(AppConstants.POOL_SIZE);

        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: `args[]` это параметры командной строки. Если вы напишите `java MyProgram one two`, то `args[0]` будет хранить `"one"`, а `args[1]` — `"two"`

Comment: Если вопрос касается именно `args`, то будет уместно указать метод, в котором объявлен массив `args` (скорее всего `main`). Соответственно если по `DataSourceFactory` вопросов нет, то код можно не указывать.